# Tool to "Data Load" or "ETL" -- from SQL Server into Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, etl

I am trying to figure out decent but simple tool which I can host myself in AWS EC2, which will allow me to pull data out of SQL Server 2005 and push to Amazon Redshift. 
I basically have a view in SQL Server on which I am doing SELECT * and I need just put all this data into Redshift. The biggest concern is that there is a lot of data, and this will need to be configurable so I can queue it, run as a nighly/continuous job, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try SSIS. All versions of SQL server except Free/Express come with SSIS for free. I don't know if it inlcudes an adapter/component to connect to Amazon redshift. Let us know if it does.

Comment: Something like Kettle may work: http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/

Answer (score 4):

alexeypro,

dump tables to files, then you have two fundamental challenges to solve:

1. Transporting data to Amazon
2. Loading data to Redshift tables.

Amazon S3 will help you with both:

1. S3 supports fast upload of files to Amazon from your SQL server location. See this [great article](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/). It is from 2011 but I did some testing a few months back and saw very similar results. I was testing with gigabytes of data and 16 uploader threads were ok, as I'm not on backbone. Key thing to remember is that compression and parallel upload are your friends to cut down the time for upload.
2. Once data are on S3, Redshift supports high-performance parallel load from files on S3 to table(s) via COPY SQL command. To get fastest load performance pre-partition your data based on table distribution key and and pre-sort it to avoid expensive vacuums. All is well documented in Amazon's [best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html). I have to say these guys know how to make things neat & simple, so just follow the steps.

If you are coder you can orchestrate the whole process remotely using scripts in whatever shell/language you want. You'll need tools/libraries for parallel HTTP upload to S3 and command line access to Redshift (psql) to launch the COPY command.

Another options is Java, there are libraries for S3 upload and JDBC access to Redshift.

As other posters suggest, you could probably use SSIS (or essentially any other ETL tool) as well. I was testing with CloverETL. Took care of automating the process as well as partitioning/presorting the files for load.

Comment: Oh and you want to read this [one](http://www.slideshare.net/joeharris76/migration-to-redshift-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Now Microsoft released SSIS Powerpack, so you can do it natively.

SSIS Amazon Redshift Data Transfer Task

```
Very fast bulk copy from on-premises data to Amazon Redshift in few clicks
Load data to Amazon Redshift from traditional DB engines like SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, DB2
Load data to Amazon Redshift from Flat Files
Automatic file archiving support
Automatic file compression support to reduce bandwidth and cost
Rich error handling and logging support to troubleshoot Redshift Datawarehouse loading issues
Support for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012, 2014 (32 bit and 64 bit)
```

Why SSIS PowerPack?

```
High performance suite of Custom SSIS tasks, transforms and adapters
```

Comment: I don't think Microsoft has a tool by that name.  You must mean the zappy one.

Answer (score 0):

With existing ETL tools, an alternate option to avoid staging data in Amazon (S3/Dynamo) is to use the commercial DataDirect Amazon Redshift Driver which supports a high performance load over the wire without additional dependencies to stage data.

https://blogs.datadirect.com/2014/10/recap-amazon-redshift-salesforce-data-integration-oow14.html

Answer (score 0):

For getting data into Amazon Redshift, I made DataDuck http://dataducketl.com/

It's like Ruby on Rails but for building ETLs.

To give you an idea of how easy it is to set up, here's how you get your data into Redshift.

1. Add `gem 'dataduck'` to your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Run `datatduck quickstart` and follow the instructions
4. This will autogenerate files representing the tables and columns you want to migrate to the data warehouse. You can modify these to customize it, e.g. remove or transform some of the columns.
5. Commit this code to your own ETL project repository
6. Git pull the code on your EC2 server
7. Run `dataduck etl all` on a cron job, from the EC2 server, to transfer all the tables into Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 0):

Why not Python+boto+psycopg2 script?
It will run on EC2 Windows or Linux instance.
If it's OS Windows you could:

1. Extract data from SQL Server( using `sqlcmd.exe`)
2. Compress it (using gzip.GzipFile).
3. Multipart upload it to S3 (using boto)
4. Append it to Amazon Redshit table (using psycopg2).

Similarly, it worked for me when I wrote [Oracle-To-Redshift-Data-Loader](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle-To-Redshift-Data-Loader)